# How to convert a byte array to binary? Python

Tags: python

So currently I have a .bin file that I read in as a byte array and get an array like this:

```
with open ('test.bin') as x:
    arrayneeded = bytearray(x.read())
    
print(arrayneeded)
```

I get an array like this:

b'\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00... etc

The question I have is, how do I do the opposite of this? Lets say I have a byte array already, how do I convert that and append it to a .bin file? I know how to write to a file already using

```
x.write()
```

I looked online and couldn't find a way to do the opposite of what I did above. Any insight would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you answered your question already. If you have bytes that you want to write to a file, you can just write them. There's no such thing as converting to binary - bytes already "are binary"

Comment: oh okay so I don't need to convert it to anything?

Comment: You need to open your file for appending in binary mode. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: append bytes to file: with open ('test.bin', mode='ab',) as x: x.write(arrayneeded)

Comment: @ligma When reading bytes, use `with open('test.bin', 'rb') as x:`.  Otherwise, the default is text mode and the data will be decoded using an OS-specific default encoding to Unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are searching for but if you want to decode your variable (i presumed that in this case is a list of integers) write it on a file and then read it you would have to do it like this:

```
my_str=[1,2,3,4,5]

byte_str = bytearray(my_str)
```

you can append it by writing "ab" as the mode

```
with open("file.bin","ab") as f:
   f.write(byte_str)
```

You don't have to convert it but just use it as it is:

```
 with open("file.bin", "rb") as f:
        x = f.read()
        print(list(x))
```